# How to create an onclick function which is called when a restart button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I am quite new to programming and am in desperate need of help.

I am trying to code a function that will carry out a resetting function upon pressing an already made reset button.  I have a rough skeleton code however I am struggling with what to write within my function to allow it to physically clear the message field and any temporary variables made along with it.

Below is my code

```
onclick="restartButtonClicked()"
function restartButtonClicked() {

document.getElementById("MessageField")  = ""

morseCode = [];
colours = [];
output = '';
message = '';
message.innerHTML = ''; 
}

document.getElementById("restartButton").onclick = restartButtonClicked;
```

I am sorry for my lack of detail but I am indeed, quite lost.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What property of `MessageField` are you trying to set to `""`? You possibly meant `document.getElementById("MessageField").value  = "";` Also, how will `message` have an `innerHTML` when you just set it to an empty string?

Comment: can I ask for your html code?

Answer (score 0):

If `messageField` is the ID of your html tag, this will reset your field:

```
document.getElementById("messageField").innerHTML = "";
```

You can add event handler to your button with both:

```
<button onclick="restartButtonClicked()" id="restartButton">restart</button>
```

and

```
document.getElementById("restartButton").addEventListener("click", restartButtonClicked);
```